error: dependency is not satisfiable: libprotobuf23 (>=3.12.4)
I am trying to download Cockatrice to play Magic The Gathering and I'm getting an error when trying to install onto Ubuntu using the package installer

Please edit your question to specify the release of Ubuntu and show us the complete input and output resulting in that error message. A link to whatever instructions you are following would also help.
